# initialized imageview in onCreate but still null

Tags: android

I want to achieve the following: Once user click a button, change current layout(main) to the other and the other layout has an image loaded. But I keep getting error message say "virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference". The following is my mainactivity.java and 'the other layout'.xml

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button mybtn;
    private ImageView myimage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){

        myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        mybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mybtn.setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
    }

    public class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            switch (v.getId()){

                case R.id.btn:
                    setContentView(R.layout.the_other_layout);
                    initMap();
            }
        }
    }

    public void initMap(){

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.somepngfile,options);
        myimage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

The follwoing is the_other_layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**:

Please check the answer below if you have the similar problem

Comment: it's because your activity is using `activity_main` layout not your other layout. you should be re-setting your layout,

Comment: I am sorry I do not get it. do you mean start another activity?

Comment: @tikael See my answer below. hope this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured another way to meet my requirement: add a new intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.super.getBaseContext(), Myanotherclass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and then this can start a new layout

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
case R.id.btn:
          setContentView(R.layout.the_other_layout);
          initMap();
```

Remove this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.the_other_layout);
```

you can not set two layout in an Activity.

**Edit**

For a fullscreen imageView:

```
 public void initMap(){
       myimage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
       myimage.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.your_image);
       myimage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
   }
```

Comment: your ImageView and  Button needs to be on `activity_main`

Comment: `<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="******.MainActivity">

    <Button
       />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
</LinearLayout>` ? may we move to chat?

Comment: did you add the button and imageview to the layout? i think then your null exception will be resolved..

Comment: I did. The main reason I want to start a new layout is that the I want the image is displayed FULLSCREEN and it looks that use one main layout is not doable? Or it is but I do not know. I am pretty new. I tried `bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.floormap),screenwidth,screenheight,true)`  does not help .

Comment: `setImageDrawable in ImageView can not be apply to (int)` error...should I still add <ImageView> in my activity_main.xml?

Comment: here us the thing  u need your imageview reference from your activity layout file...and  apply setimagedrawable to that imageview...it works in my studio..can not be apply to int this error shouldn't shown..u r clearly mising the concept..

Comment: `imgv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.floormap));` fixed the error, but still not full screen, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The reason is myimage is not part of activity_main.xml
so you need to move it after setContentView(....)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private Button mybtn;
private ImageView myimage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

public void init(){

    mybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    mybtn.setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
}

public class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btn:
                setContentView(R.layout.the_other_layout);
                myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
                initMap();
        }
    }
}

public void initMap(){

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    ......
}
```

}

Comment: does this setting works for me ? It does not for me and I figured another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `initMap()` method. You did not re-initialized `myimage` with the `ImageView` id `android:id="@+id/imgview"` of your layout `the_other_layout.xml`.

**Update your `initMap()` as below:**

```
public void initMap() {

    // ImageView
    myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.somepngfile,options);

    myimage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Hope this will help~